# Datatablejs : Search not working for JOIN table result

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have integrated **Datatable** (https://datatables.net) for the listing of records in the Admin Panel. All default functionality (Searching, Sorting) was working fine when I was fetching data/result from single table.

**But when I require joining two tables**, I am facing below error because of Datatable auto search for every column that you named in your JS code.

**Error**:

```
Column not found: - Unknown column
```

**JS code:**

```
{ data: "iBookingId","width": "3%","bSortable":false},(=> From booking)<br>
{ data: "vName","width": "10%","bSortable":false},(=> From users)<br>
{ data: "email","width": "15%","bSortable":false},(=> From users)<br>
{ data: "dDate","width": "7%","bSortable":false},(=> From booking)<br>
```

How can I resolve that? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

After many efforts, I found the solution.

**Simply, you just need to pass new attribute "name" along with data so datatable will search for that column.**

```
{ data: "iBookingId" ,"width": "3%","bSortable":false},
{ data: "vName",name: 'users.vName' ,"width": "10%","bSortable":false},
{ data: "email",name: 'users.email' ,"width": "15%","bSortable":false},
{ data: "dDate" ,"width": "7%","bSortable":false},
```

PS: Don't apply `searchable: false` as a patch. :P